# Биндинг действия

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть несколько кнопок

```
<button class='view-images'></button>
<button class='view-videos'></button>
<button class='view-html'></button>
```

Каждая кнопка вызывает событие:

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    $(this).trigger('append', '..data..');
});
```

И есть 3 события:

```
$('.view-images').bind('append', function(e, data) {
    alert('images');
});

$('.view-videos').bind('append', function(e, data) {
    alert('videos');
});

$('.view-html').bind('append', function(e, data) {
    alert('html');
});
```

По сути когда мы кликаем на определенную кнопку, то должно происходить событие, но оно не происходит. Как правильно сделать?

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
    $(this).trigger('append', '..data..');
});

$('.view-images').bind('append', function(e, data) {
 alert('images');
});
 
$('.view-videos').bind('append', function(e, data) {
 alert('videos');
});
 
$('.view-html').bind('append', function(e, data) {
 alert('html');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class='view-images'>images</button>
<button class='view-videos'>videos</button>
<button class='view-html'>html</button>
```

Comment: Есть вкратце, то вы во первых обработчик клика не вешаете. Синтаксис неверный, можете через тот же on.

Во-вторых изнутри обработчика клика к кликаемому элементу неправильно обращаетесь. Можно черзе $(this).

В третьих лучше использовать on вместо bind как говорит сама дока jQuery

Comment: Почему-то тут пример заработал, не пойму в чем дело.

Comment: ну так вы весь основной втф из своего кода правкой вычистили, вот он и заработал)

Comment: @Утка не, баг был как раз именно в том, что не учел момент с динамическими элементами. Увы, ошибки в примере - это мой косяк.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте срабатывания кнопок по клику и выбирайте их по классу:

```
$('.view-images').click(function(){
         alert('images');
});

$('.view-videos').click(function(){
      alert('videos');
});

$('.view-html').click(function(){
      alert('html');
});
```

Comment: .bind() кстати лучше не использовать, так как он не срабатывает на элементах появившися после его установки

Comment: точно, прошляпил, момент с биндом динамических элементов.

Answer (score 2):

`$button` на `$(this)` меняем :

```js
  $(function() {
    $('button').on('click', function() {
      $(this).trigger('append', this);
    });

    $('.view-images').on('append', function(e, data) {
      alert('images');
      console.log(data);
    });

    $('.view-videos').bind('append', function(e, data) {
      alert('videos');
      console.log(data);
    });

    $('.view-html').bind('append', function(e, data) {
      alert('html');
      console.log(data);
    });

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='view-images'>images</button>
<button class='view-videos'>videos</button>
<button class='view-html'>html</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно навесить обработчик вот так, код заработает:

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  $(this).trigger('append')
})

$('.view-images').bind('append', function(e, data) {
 alert('images');
});
 
$('.view-videos').bind('append', function(e, data) {
 alert('videos');
});
 
$('.view-html').bind('append', function(e, data) {
 alert('html');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='view-images'>images</button>
<button class='view-videos'>videos</button>
<button class='view-html'>html</button>
```